# How to Protect an Exe File from Decompilation

Tags: exe, executable, reverse-engineering, decompiling, source-code-protection

What are the methods for protecting an Exe file from Reverse Engineering.Many Packers are available to pack an exe file.Such an approach is mentioned in [http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/07/protecting-your-c-programexe-files-from.html](http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/07/protecting-your-c-programexe-files-from.htmlhh)

Is this method efficient?

Comment: Oh, and there is no such thing as to "protect" an executable from reverse-engineering. If it can be run, it can be reverse-engineered. Packers and other tools just raise the bar for reverse-engineering.

Comment: @Ira "One can surely make programs that can't be reverse engineered." Is this a hypothesis or a fact? Could you supply an example? You really piqued my interest. Do you mean that you can write code for a given machine, so that the machine produces a well defined output for a given input and -possessing this piece of code- you cannot get any notion of the rules that lead from input to output and hence cannot rewrite it?

Answer (score 18):

The only good way to prevent a program from being reverse-engineered ("understood") is to revise its structure to essentially force the opponent into understanding Turing Machines.  Essentially what you do is:

- take some problem which generally proven to be computationally difficult
- synthesize a version of that whose outcome you know; this is generally pretty easy compared to *solving* a version
- make the correct program execution dependent on the correct answer
- make the program compute nonsense if the answer is not correct

Now an opponent staring at your code has to figure what the "correct" computation is, by solving algorithmically hard problems.  There's tons of NP-hard problems that nobody has solved efficiently in the literature in 40 years; its a pretty good bet if your program depends on one of these, that J. Random Reverse-Engineer won't suddenly be able to solve them.

One generally does this by transforming the original program to obscure its control flow, and/or its dataflow. Some techniques scramble the control flow by converting some control flow into essentially data flow ("jump indirect through this pointer array"), and then implementing data flow algorithms that require precise points-to analysis, which is both provably hard and has proven difficult in practice.

Here's a paper that describes a variety of techniques rather shallowly but its an easy read:
http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/stamp/students/kundu_deepti.pdf

Here's another that focuses on how to ensure that the obfuscating transformations lead to results that are gauranteed to be computationally hard:
http://www.springerlink.com/content/41135jkqxv9l3xme/

Here's one that surveys a wide variety of control flow transformation methods,
including those that provide levels of gaurantees about security:
http://www.springerlink.com/content/g157gxr14m149l13/

This paper obfuscates control flows in binary programs with low overhead:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.167.3773&rank=2

Now, one could go through a lot of trouble to prevent a program from being decompiled.  But if the decompiled one was impossible to understand, you simply might not bother; that's the approach I'd take.

If you insist on preventing decompilation, you can attack that by considering what decompilation is intended to accomplish.  Decompilation essentially proposes that you can convert each byte of the target program into some piece of code.  One way to make that fail, is to ensure that the application can apparently use each byte
as both computer instructions, and as data, even if if does not actually do so, and that the decision to do so is obfuscated by the above kinds of methods.  One variation on this is to have lots of conditional branches in the code that are in fact unconditional (using control flow obfuscation methods); the other side of the branch falls into nonsense code that looks valid but branches to crazy places in the existing code.  Another variant on this idea is to implement your program as an obfuscated interpreter, and implement the actual functionality as a set of interpreted data.
A fun way to make this fail is to generate code at run time and execute it on the fly; most conventional languages such as C have pretty much no way to represent this.

A program built like this would be difficult to decompile, let alone understand after the fact.

Tools that are claimed to a good job at protecting binary code are listed at:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/any-comprehensive-solutions-for-binary-code-protection-and-anti-reverse-engineeri

Answer (score 5):

Packing, compressing and any other methods of binary protection will only every serve to hinder or slow reversal of your code, they have never been and never will be 100% secure solutions (though the marketing of some would have you believe that). You basically need to evaluate what sort of level of hacker you are up against, if they are script kids, then any packer that require *real effort and skill* (ie:those that lack unpacking scripts/programs/tutorials) will deter them. If your facing people with skills and resources, then you can forget about keeping your code safe (as many of the comments say: if the OS can read it to execute it, so can you, it'll just take a while longer). If your concern is not so much your IP but rather the security of something your program does, then you might be better served in redesigning in a manner where it cannot be attack even with the original source (chrome takes this approach).

Comment: +1 For "redesigning in a manner where it cannot be attack even with the original source". Security by Obscurity never has and never will work.

Comment: There are no security protections that are 100% secure. Even all that cryptographic stuff we have isn't safe.  The question is, "is the amount of work to break the security significant, and will it discourage some large class of attackers?"  If the answer is yes, then the security scheme is useful.

Comment: If security is a concern you can better not use any software at all. And yep, if the OS or the processor understands the binary, so can anyone else. +1

Comment: @WTP: "Executes the binary" is far different than "understand the program" or "can make arbitrary desired changes".

Answer (score 1):

Decompilation is always possible. The statement

> This threat can be eliminated to extend by packing/compressing  the
>   executable(.exe).

on your linked site is a plain lie.

Comment: I think that's too strong.  If the encoding of a program is couple to the successful execution of a Turing machine, you might have to decide if the Turing machine halts to get the right decoding. CS says you can't do that. So there's some hope for anti-decompilers.   Whether the one at the linked website is any good is another question.  Also note the OP asked about defense against reverse engineering, not just decompilation. (APL programs have proven to be pretty resistant in the past :)

Comment: @Ira I can't follow you there. If the environment that executes the code (be it a RE, a processor, an abacus) does what the program wants it to do, then obviously the code has been read successfully. If my Runtime Environment can do this, so can I and hence disassemblation is always possible. Or am I wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Currently many solutions can be used to protect your application from being anti-compiled. Such as compressing, Obfuscation, Code snippet, etc.
You can looking for a company to help you achieve this.

Such as Nelpeiron, the website is:https://www.nalpeiron.com/
Which can cover many platforms, Windows, Linux, ARM-Linux, Android.

What is more Virbox is also can be taken into consideration:
The website is: https://lm-global.virbox.com/index.html
I recommend is because they have more options to protect your source code, such as import table protection, memory check.